# How to retrieve one particular record from a database without using cursors?

Tags: c#, sql, db2

I have the following records in a table from my DB2 database :

```
num    f1     f2     f3
------------------------
***    e1     e2     e3
A      e1     e2     e3
***    e4     e5     e6
```

The "key" (not primary) of each row is made from the combination of the fields f1, f2 and f3.
I must get rows following this rule : if, for one key, there are multiple lines, I must select the row where the field "num" doesn't contain the value "***". Otherwise, if the key is unique, I must select the row.

In my example, I should return "A" for the key e1, e2, e3 and "***" for the key e4, e5, e6

I made it work by using a temporary table, where I insert the correct lines while using a cursor to read the main table. But it's slow, very slow.

Is there a way to use only one SQL query to get the correct records, or with a C# program (the language my app uses) ? I tried to play with Datatables and LINQ, without success.

Thanks for your help

Comment: `Otherwise, if the key is unique, I must select the row` What about the other case? A non-unique value that isn't `***`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you simply mean something like

```
SELECT MIN(num), f1, f2, f3 from myTable
group by f1, f2, f3
```

I'm not sure about the MIN, maybe its MAX, I have no DB2 at hand to check the ordering of 'A' and '*'

EDIT:
This works only if '***' is either the smallest or the biggest possibly value

Comment: That did it. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```sql
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM 
myTable
ORDER BY CASE WHEN num = '***' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END    
WHERE f1 = something
AND f2 = something
AND f3 = something
```

That is, you order it so values equaling '***' are pushed to the bottom, apply filtering, and select the first row.